# Edit cell value in vaadin table

Tags: java, vaadin, java-ee-6

I am new to Vaadin 7. I am facing a problem with vaadin table. Currently my data is displaying in vaadin table, in that table each row got one button. When I click that button, I want to change particular cell value in the same row.

```
table.setEditable(true)
```

Ex: In a row I have two columns "name" and "button". when I click button I want change name value in same row.

Suppose in first row column name value is "ABC" , when I click button, I want to change to value "ABC" to "XYZ".

Comment: What have you done so far, and what is (not) happening?

Comment: Hello Andre Schild,